# What's the best way to generate bookmarklet in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bookmarklet

I have a Javascript that I want to embed in a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href="javascript:function() {...}();">
```

I created a partial called _bookmarklet.html.erb which generates the javascript, including links that are dynamically generated to point to assets in app/assets. It cannot be static because it creates url's that point to the assets on the current server, which need to be absolute because, after it is installed, the bookmarklet could be executed on a different web host.

My template looks like this:

```
<a href="<%= render :partial => 'pages/bookmarklet' %>"
```

The problem I'm having is the " (double-quotes") in the javascript. Is there a mechanism for escaping the quotes? How can I embed this properly? What is the right way to expose the bookmarklet in Rails?

Comment: I've tried the options suggested below as well as escape_javascript. escape_javascript escapes the quotes like \" instead of &quot;. I guess what I really need is some way of escaping html characters (<, ", >). Surely there is a Rails helper for this?

Comment: h doesn't do anything. Since my javascript is not actually HTML (there are no tags) there's nothing for it to escape.

Comment: I tried creating a helper that uses CGI.escape to encode the javascript as an url, but the browser doesn't recognize "javascript%3A%28function%28%29%7Bfunction+src_script...." as javascript. Even if I just try to substitute the "'s with &quot;, that also throws off the parser ("Illegal token &").

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple options.  You could use the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper to perform escaping for you:

```
link_to "Bookmarklet!", render(:partial => 'pages/bookmarklet')
```

Or [manually escaping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-h) the node's attribute via:

```
<a href="<%=h render :partial => 'pages/bookmarklet' %>"
```

Comment: Neither of these escape the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several](https://github.com/Octo-Labs/easymarklet) [gems](https://github.com/oliverfriedmann/rails-bookmarklet) that allow you to create a bookmarklet. Anyhow to escape and render the JavaScript on a href you should treat the partial as a string:

`<%= link_to "Bookmarklet", "#{render 'bookmarklet'}" %>`

[Here](http://as-cii.github.io/2014/03/bookmarklet-on-a-href-in-rails.html) is also a step-by-step guide to create a bookmarklet in rails without any gem.